# Find structure to which *ast.FuncDecl attached

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

Here is simple realisation of Handler interface:

```
type someApi struct {
    mu       *sync.RWMutex
}
func (api *someApi) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}

func NewSomeApi(mu *sync.RWMutex) *someApi {
    return &someApi{
        mu: mu,
    }
}

func (srv *someApi) Create() {
  // some realisation
}

func Create() {
  // some realisation
}
```

I want parse file with `go/ast` and create decorator for `someApi.Create` function.
It simple to get func name with `*ast.FuncDecl.Name`, but how can I find which of `Create` funcs attached to `someApi`?

Comment: Use [FuncDecl.Recv](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#FuncDecl.Recv) to find the receiver type name.  I find it helps to look at [a dump](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew#Dump) of a parsed file when trying to understand how to use the go/ast package.

Answer (score 1):

Sloved this by iterating through `*ast.FuncDecl.Recv.List`:

```
for _, l := range fn.Recv.List { // fn is *ast.FuncDecl
    star, ok := l.Type.(*ast.StarExpr)
    if !ok {
        continue
    }
    fmt.Println(star.X) // someApi
}
```